# How to send username, password and click submit button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to send my username, password and click my submit button that is within a nested div class element.

So does my HTML code look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"/>
    <title>Matilda Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vertical-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h4>LOGIN</h4>
                    <form action="/login" method="post" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="e497ff0a-993c-41ad-bf03-54c79a7756e9"/>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" >Benutzername</label>:
                            <input type="text"
                                   id="username"
                                   name="username"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   autofocus="autofocus"
                                   placeholder="Username"/>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" >Passwort</label>:
                                <input type="password"
                                   id="password"
                                   name="password"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="Password"/>
                        </div>                <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <input type="submit"
                                           name="login-submit"
                                           id="login-submit"
                                           class="form-control btn btn-info"
                                           value="Log In"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Integration test but I do not know how to input the user ADMIN and my password and then click the submit button.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.row input[class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3']"));
for(WebElement el : elements) 
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("ADMIN");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password"); 
}
```

Maybe someone could help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to click the  _submit button_ or you want to _get the username and password_?

Comment: Please post the html here for username & password input field.You have posted html for button element not username & password.

Comment: I am really sorry, I am a complete .... I want to send username, password and then click the submit button. Both is not working - I think the last night was too short to think clearly, I am sorry.

Comment: is your form inside any frame? I am just curious? Please check any ```iframe``` is there or not?

Comment: No, there is not any iframe that I am using. I will edit my initial post with my complete HTML code. Just a hint: I use Spring Boot with Thymeleaf, if that should change something significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand, why you are using for cycle. In easiest form you need this kind of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("ADMIN");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit")).click();
```

With PageObjects it will be some different.

Comment: Well, this I already tried and I always get this error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"username"}

Comment: @Bernd Then you probably need to add a wait. Given the HTML you posted, there's no reason that this code won't work.

Comment: You were totally right. It is working now. Thank you very much.